# Can rel="prev" and rel="next" attributes be placed on elements other than <link>?

Tags: seo, html, pagination, hyperlink

Is this the absolute **ONLY** correct way to indicate a paginated series of pages to search engines?

```html
<head>
  <link href="www.example.co.uk/news/?page=8" rel="prev">
  <link href="www.example.co.uk/news/?page=10" rel="next">
</head>
```

Or can `rel="prev"` and `rel="next"` as attributes be added to other elements, for instance `a` in the `body`? Example:

```html
<a href="www.example.co.uk/news/?page=8" rel="prev">Previous</a>
<a href="www.example.co.uk/news/?page=10" rel="next">Next</a>
```

I have read [Google's documentation](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html) on implementing `rel="prev/next"`, but it doesn't really specifically say that in the `<head>` on a `<link>` is the absolute only way to correctly implement, definitively.

Comment: Same question, but only about Google: [Does rel=“next” have to be in the HEAD?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/103471/17633)

Comment: My question is also "about Google" if you read it. That thread also doesn't actually have a definitive answer, much like this one presently.

Comment: Your question doesn’t say that it’s only about Google Search; your first sentence says "to search engines". But if it is, your question should be closed as duplicate (shouldn’t matter whether or not the answers satisfy -- if it’s closed as duplicate, the question can still be found and answers would be posted at the duplicate target).

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not the absolute only correct way to indicate a paginated series of pages to search engines.

According to the [HTML specification for the anchor tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element), the rel attribute is valid on anchor tags, so you could do it the way you have in your second example.

Comment: Thanks Cpt. Dob. Would you also be able to confirm that this implementation is not just valid HTML, but valid for search engines' understanding?